# При запуске виртуальной машины VMware Workstation Player не работает мышь и клавиатура

Tags: macos, клавиатура, vmware, виртуальная-машина, мышь

Пытаюсь виртуальзировать MacOS при помощи VMware Workstation Player. Установка и настройка проходят без проблем, но когда я запускаю виртуальную машину MacOS, появляется экран с яблоком, и после клика на этом экране, мышь исчезает и не реагируют вместе с клавиатурой вплоть до выхода из машины (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>).

Кроме того возникает сообщение:

> "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine."

При выборе `Player > Manage > Install VMware Tools` ничего не происходит, только пункт меню меняет название на Cancel VMware Tools Installation.
Repair тоже ничего не даёт.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках виртуальной машины для USB-контролера задать режим USB-совместимости 2.0 вместо 1.1
[image: USB Compatibility]